# Can't read property "useLayoutEffect" of undefined from vendor.js file

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

This error doesn't appear in localhost, it only appears in the dev / stage / etc environments.

```
vendors.c058a202.chunk.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'useLayoutEffect' of undefined
    at vendors.c058a202.chunk.js:2
    at vendors.c058a202.chunk.js:2
    at Module.<anonymous> (vendors.c058a202.chunk.js:2)
    at i (client.991c6b9d.js:formatted:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendors.c058a202.chunk.js:2)
    at i (client.991c6b9d.js:formatted:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendors.c058a202.chunk.js:2)
    at i (client.991c6b9d.js:formatted:38)
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendors.c058a202.chunk.js:2)
    at i (client.991c6b9d.js:formatted:38)
```

**Any thoughts on where to look?** I didn't see any package.json updates. We don't actually push package-lock.json to the repo. The docker container runs nginx with static webpack build files, but running that locally doesn't reproduce the issue either.

Comment: is react missing?

Comment: @JulianKleine it sure looks like a peer dependency react is, but react was never removed from the install

Comment: I mean is it injected to the html page or bundled with webpack? Just trying to understand what your page loads

Comment: @JulianKleine Good question, it's bundled, no fancy webpack configs I can see. Just some basic webpack production build of vendor and client JS files

Comment: Did you try to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` locally, then `npm i`, then build and host the html files locally to see if you can reproduce the error?

Comment: Turns out a package was updated and the carat allowed the install without a package-lock in the repo to update to the latest package which was broken. So one of the packages was auto upgraded. I thought I replaced node modules locally but I didn't notice the issue.

Comment: You should always commit your package-lock.json to the repo, it's best practice to avoid these kind of issues.

Comment: @JulianKleine Oh I totally agree! I've tried to convince the engineering team but was unsuccessful

Comment: out of interest, what is their biggest concern?

Comment: @JulianKleine that it's a large team and there are many PRs and it's an MVP so they'd prefer not to spend time adjusting the package-lock conflicts. A large team of 10 devs pushing changes regularly does make this difficult so I do understand.

Comment: I am working in a large dev team and usually those conflicts don't happen. If some happen, then just choose to resolve one way, commit, remove the package-lock and the node_modules, go for a clean install, commit the new package lock and merge. Easy life.